# The padding-top value dynamicly generated from .height

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I doing this correctly? as it is not working... `$('#page').css('padding-top': ($headerHeight + 'px'));` the `$headerHeight` is from `var headerHeight = header.height();`.

I am trying to calculate the height of the #header and set it as padding-top for #page

```
//Sticky header on offset
var header = document.querySelector('#header.sticky');
var headerOffset = header.offsetTop;
var headerHeight = header.height();
function scroll () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= headerOffset) {
        $('#header').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0','left':'0','right':'0','z-index':'9999',});
        $('#page').css('padding-top': ($headerHeight + 'px'));
    } else {
        $('#header').css({'position':'relative'});
        $('#page').css('padding-top': '0');
    }
} document.onscroll = scroll;
```

**Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4LPz/3/**

Comment: What is wrong with your code??? Explain it

Comment: Is $('#page').css('padding-top': ($headerHeight + 'px')); correct? It is not doing anything

Comment: Check value of `$headerHeight`, is it returning expected value?

Comment: Alert it or log it: `alert($headerHeight);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51528/discussion-between-leo-and-a-wolff)

Comment: If you want specific help, provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/f4LPz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height()` is a jquery method, so it should be:

```
var $headerHeight = $(header).height();
```

### jsFiddle

Comment: This fixed the paddings for the #page, however now - the #header is being switched to fixed when the window reaches its bottom and not top... why do you think this is caused because?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Doesn't jsFiddle is what you are expecting?!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .css() expects a plain object of key-value pairs, moreover $headerHeight is not the name for your variable, "headerHeight" is. So you should change:

```
$('#page').css('padding-top': ($headerHeight + 'px'));
```

by:

```
$('#page').css({'padding-top': (headerHeight + 'px')});
```

That change should do the work.

Best.

Comment: Nope, the weird thing is, the header works if I removed that line above